# PHP - How to group from multiple sql queries

Tags: mysql, while-loop, fetch

I got

```
for($i = $start_date;$start_date <= $end_date;$i->modify('+1 day')) {
        $i->format('Y-m-d').'<br />';
    $dates = $i->format('Y-m-d');
    echo $query = "
SELECT md.dish_id
     , md.daydate
     , d.id
     , d.dish_name
     , d.weight
     , d.price 
  FROM dishes d
  LEFT 
  JOIN menu_details md 
    ON d.id = md.dish_id
 WHERE md.daydate = '$dates' 
";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo 'Date: '.$row['daydate'].'Name: '.$row['dish_name'].'<br />';
     }
```

how can i row 'dish_name' for every date on a new row.In the database there are more then 1 row with same date=

Comment: Performance issues aside, a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions is a little odd, and may provide unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to avoid running queries in loops...

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT md.dish_id, md.daydate, d.id, d.dish_name, d.weight, d.price
FROM dishes d
LEFT JOIN menu_details md ON (d.id = md.dish_id)
WHERE md.daydate BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
GROUP BY md.daydate ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'Date: '.$row['daydate'].'Name: '.$row['dish_name'].'<br />';
}
```

What is the group by for? I think it may cause you to lose some of the results...

Comment: Yes, you are right but how to echo the dish_names for the specific date?

Comment: I asked about the group by because it would mean that the query would not retrieve all dishes for a given date - it will group by date and hence return just one. The code I posted should echo each result as before... If it there is something else its not doing then provide some additional information.